# Why does my MacBook only connect to bluetooth headset when it's just been turned on?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, headphones

I run 10.10.4 on an Macbook Pro 9,2. When my bluetooth headphones are on and I try to connect with them, nothing happens. I then need to turn off the headphones and turn them on again, at which point they automatically connect (provided the two devices have been paired). When i `Disconnect` the device and then try to reconnect, nothing happens. Why is this so? Why is there a `Connect` option for each paired device if it does not work? Can the problem be at the headphone's end?

Comment: I would guess that it is on the headphone's side. Do the headphones work normally on other devices? Do other bluetooth devices show the same behavior when paired to your MBP?

Comment: I need to try with other bt devices, but I experience the same with my iPod touch and the headphones so you may be right.

Comment: Do they pair if you turn restart the bluetooth on your MBP? Might be a workaround to make an automator service doing so.